# how to insert database with generate id every new value using java gui ms access

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I want to insert database with value and generate ID[0-9][0-9]
if there already 1 like IDA01 it will generate IDA02
if there is no data, then it will select max value and generate next ID
I use eclipse and ms access as database

[image]

Comment: you can fetch max from db, calculate the next one and then insert. But this approach will work in single threaded environment.

Comment: I try now thank you... I already try max from db but still not working

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Please tag it in the question

Comment: Maybe ERD i think